# setting up iBeacon on two devices Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode5, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, nsnotifications

I am experimenting with a game app that uses iBeacon to notify a user that another person wants to connect with them to play one of eight games.  I have created the peripheral Manager and various regions (one for each game using a unique uuid and region.identifier.  Since I am using the same view controller to both transmit the iBeacon info and receive it I have the user tap a button to either set the device to broadcast the specific game beacon info or tap another button to receive that specific game beacon info. Here is some code;

//this sets the transmitter

```
-(void) configureTransmitter {
    // The received signal strength indicator (RSSI) value (measured in decibels) for the device. This value represents the measured strength of the beacon from one meter away and is used during ranging. Specify nil to use the default value for the device.
   NSNumber * power = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-63];
    self.peripheralData = [self.beaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:power];
    // Get the global dispatch queue.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    // Create a peripheral manager.
    self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue];
}

-(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    // The peripheral is now active, this means the bluetooth adapter is all good so we can start advertising.
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;

    }

}
```

//this creates the beacon for the transmitter

```
NSUUID * uid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:UUIDString];
        self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid identifier:identifierString];
```

//these are the button actions that configure the beacon and have the peripheralManager start advertising that info.  Each have its own UUID and identifier.

```
-(IBAction)checkersInvite:(id)sender;{


     self.inviteField.text = @"com.checkers.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"3B257014-2C29-40E0-8E1E-1D7A9E5D0964";
   [self configureTransmitter];

    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];

    [self.inviteCheckers setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}




-(IBAction)chessInvite:(id)sender;{

    self.inviteField.text = @"com.chess.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"0F45FE1A-C4B7-4772-936C-271ADB388367";
    [self configureTransmitter];

    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];

    [self.inviteChess setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(IBAction)backgammonInvite:(id)sender;{
    self.inviteField.text = @"com.backgammon.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"23F10764-F8FF-4DA2-8577-F639D2B11DFA";
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
    [self.inviteBackgammon setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(IBAction)starBattleInvite:(id)sender;{
    self.inviteField.text = @"com.starBattle.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"29CA193C-AA40-4984-A22D-02797FA84583";
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
   [self.inviteStarBattle setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(IBAction)mankalaInvite:(id)sender;{
    self.inviteField.text = @"com.mankala.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"83FDD95F-DADA-4593-BD0C-5275F71A2108";
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
    [self.inviteMankala setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(IBAction)captureVInvite:(id)sender;{
    self.inviteField.text = @"com.captureV.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"D1E35DF5-1615-4919-826B-1A62302B38D7";
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
    [self.inviteCaptureV setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(IBAction)penteInvite:(id)sender;{
    self.inviteField.text = @"com.pente.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"ADD6255F-C170-4EBD-B534-2C2D3BC39F7E";
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
   [self.invitePente setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(IBAction)linkIVInvite:(id)sender;{
    self.inviteField.text = @"com.linkIV.bluetooth";
    identifierString = inviteField.text;
    self.UUIDString = @"880BA4CB-1E01-4138-904A-DB40F86F0549";
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.peripheralData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(changeuuid:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
    [self.inviteLinkIV setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accept.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

-(void)changeuuid:(NSTimer *)timer{
    self.UUIDString = @"9F0ED9D4-C40A-4BFE-A8B3-C183365D8303";
    [self.peripheralManager stopAdvertising];
}
```

//I included a timer to reset the info so the user can send out another call if no one responds.

//then I set up the receiver beacons each to correspond with the game info being sent.

```
 NSUUID * uid2 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"3B257014-2C29-40E0-8E1E-1D7A9E5D0964"];
        self.beaconRegion2 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid2 identifier:@"com.checkers.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion2 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion2 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion2 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid3 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"0F45FE1A-C4B7-4772-936C-271ADB388367"];
        self.beaconRegion3 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid3 identifier:@"com.chess.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion3 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion3 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion3 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid4 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"23F10764-F8FF-4DA2-8577-F639D2B11DFA"];
        self.beaconRegion4 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid4 identifier:@"com.backgammon.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion4 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion4 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion4 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid5 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"29CA193C-AA40-4984-A22D-02797FA84583"];
        self.beaconRegion5 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid5 identifier:@"com.starBattle.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion5 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion5 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion5 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid6 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"83FDD95F-DADA-4593-BD0C-5275F71A2108"];
        self.beaconRegion6 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid6 identifier:@"com.mankala.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion6 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion6 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion6 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid7 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"D1E35DF5-1615-4919-826B-1A62302B38D7"];
        self.beaconRegion7 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid7 identifier:@"com.captureV.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion7 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion7 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion7 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid8 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"ADD6255F-C170-4EBD-B534-2C2D3BC39F7E"];
        self.beaconRegion8 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid8 identifier:@"com.pente.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion8 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion8 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion8 setNotifyOnExit:YES];

         NSUUID * uid9 = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"880BA4CB-1E01-4138-904A-DB40F86F0549"];
        self.beaconRegion9 = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uid9 identifier:@"com.linkIV.bluetooth"];
        // When set to YES, the location manager sends beacon notifications when the user turns on the display and the device is already inside the region.
        [self.beaconRegion9 setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion9 setNotifyOnEntry:YES];
        [self.beaconRegion9 setNotifyOnExit:YES];



    }
```

//then I configure the receivers for each beacon

```
-(void) configureReceiver {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion2];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion2];


}

-(void) configureReceiver2 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion3];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion3];

}

-(void) configureReceiver3 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion4];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion4];
   }


-(void) configureReceiver4 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion5];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion5];
   }


-(void) configureReceiver5 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion6];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion6];
    }


-(void) configureReceiver6 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion7];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion7];
    }


-(void) configureReceiver7 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion8];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion8];
    }


-(void) configureReceiver8 {
    // Location manager.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion9];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion9];
    }
```

//and these are the button actions for the loading of the receivers

```
-(IBAction)reciever:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver];

}
-(IBAction)reciever2:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver2];

}
-(IBAction)reciever3:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver3];

}
-(IBAction)reciever4:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver4];

}
-(IBAction)reciever5:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver5];

}
-(IBAction)reciever6:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver6];

}
-(IBAction)reciever7:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver7];

}
-(IBAction)reciever8:(id)sender;{
    [self configureReceiver8];

}
```

//and here I hand off the information to launch the notification to app delegate

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    // See if we've entered the region.
    if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.checkers.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play checkers?";

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }


  if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.chess.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Chess?";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

   if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.backgammon.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Backgammon?";


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

   if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.starBattle.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Star Battle?";


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

    if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.mankala.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Mankala?";


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

   if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.captureV.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Capture V?";


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

   if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.pente.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Pente?";


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

  if ([region.identifier isEqualToString:@"com.linkIV.bluetooth"]) {
        UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Want to play Link IV?";


        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
}
```

so to summerize

1. one user opens the app and taps on the receive checkers button configuring the beacon receiver to let them know if another user is asking if someone wants to play checkers.
2. another user opens the app and taps on the transmitter button to invite someone to play checkers.
3. when this happens user one should get a notification on screen asking if they want to play checkers.

However this does not happen.
This happens when user two taps twice on the checkers button and then once on the chess button once.

this is true for all the games.

I say I'll receive requests for backgammon.  You press backgammon button twice and then chess button  .  I receive a notification asking if I want to play backgammon

Can anyone look at my code and let me know what is going on here.

Comment: Why do you stop advertising after 10 seconds?  Core Location can take longer than that to detect a region entry.  I suspect that this is causing the problems you describe.  Remove the timer and see what happens

Comment: I have tried this to no avail.  And it only happens if I tap the chess button after tapping twice on the other one twice.  I am getting a warning that                                                                      2014-06-23 10:03:03.352  BTLE[1778:60b] CoreBluetooth[API MISUSE] <CBPeripheralManager: 0x16553750> can only accept this command while in the powered on state                                                       could this have a bearing on this

Comment: You should set your buttons to enabled=NO until you get then powered on state and then set enabled to YES

Comment: I figured this out.  Dummy me: if you look at the inaction for chessInvite it has [self configureTransmitter}; whereas backgammon and after don't  This is why I had to tap the chess button to make anything work.  Then instead of creating the UUIDString and the identifierString in the actions and passing them to the beaconRegion I just created the appropriate beacon region within each action.  Now I just have to tap the correct button once to have the notification show up.  Thanks for all the input  I really appreciate it.